# What's the drawback of using Camunda Community edition vs Enterprise, in a production environment?

Tags: production, camunda

I've recently started to get into Camunda (version 7). I have already develoiped a few workflows, and everything is running smoothly, including the basic Cockpit, which I find highly useful.

Now I want to put my workflows into production. What are the limitations of doing so, using only the Community edition, instead of the Enterprise one? Am I losing out on something important by not going for the full commercial service?

Will I encounter any limitations down the road that will block my workflows?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a comparison of Camunda 7 CE and EE here:
https://camunda.com/enterprise/

There is no (e.g. volume) limitation on engine level you will be surprised by later on. Apart from commercial support, the additional Cockpit features are very useful and Optimize to add business analytics to your environment may also be of interest.